# Refresh a div on success instead of refreshing the whole page using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, html, refresh

How can I refresh only a div on success instead of refreshing the whole page using Ajax?

```
$('a.add-to-cart').click(function (e) {
    var url = "<?php echo createItemLink($row['id']);?>";
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "<?php echo SITEURL;?>/ajax/addtoCart.php",
        data: 'itemid=<?php echo $row['id'];?>&price=<?php echo $row['price'];?>&name=<?php echo $row['title'];?>',
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#status").fadeIn(300).delay(800).fadeOut(300).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
                $(this).html(msg);
                $(location).attr('href',url);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's assume div id's is theDiv

```
success: function (msg) {
    $("#status").fadeIn(300).delay(800).fadeOut(300).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
        $('#theDiv').html(msg);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here div class is class name of div which you want to replace with msg

```
    success: function (msg) {
      <br> $(.divclass).html(msg);
      <br>  });
    <br>}
```